# Can vim commands be mapped to key combinations with >1 modifier (e.g. ctrl-alt-v)

Tags: vim, macvim

Is it possible to map a vim command to a combination of keys involving more than one modifier? For example: `ctrl-alt-v`.

As far as I can tell, the only modifier key that can be used in combination with another is shift. e.g. `<C-v>` and `<C-V>`. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yeah, you would map `<C-A-v>` or `<C-M-v>` (A, Alt, and M, Meta are equivalent concepts).  See [`:help key-notation`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#key-notation).

Comment: This DOES NOT WORK in Macvim.  Vim won't complain but modifiers after the first are ignored.  So if you do `<C-S-h>` for example, the shift is ignored.  I can't say for other versions of vim.

Comment: It doesn't work (for me, at least) in (normal, terminal-based) `vim` on a Mac either, so it doesn't appear to be specifically a MacVim issue, but rather an issue with `vim` on a Mac.

Comment: Odd. the help only mention Shift with the F keys, but not even that works for me. no modifier allowed with Fkey it seems.

Comment: To expand on @sean's comment - If you're using MacVim, see: [this superuser question](http://superuser.com/questions/280512/mapping-keys-in-vim-on-mac)

Answer (score 4):

There's also this script ([arpeggio](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2425)) that allows you to use two or more simultaneously pressed keys (any keys, not just modifiers keys like shift, alt, etc.) in your mappings.

Comment: Cool, I love the name. Can I use it to play Bach?

Comment: Great plugin, very intuitive once it's set up.

For example, I can type one bracket like normal then some code and then the closing bracket or I can just map `[]` to `[]<Left>` and hit them both at the same time ending up inside the brackets.

Better yet, it saves on boilerplate, ie `Arpeggio inoremap pc <Esc>biclass <Esc>ea():<Left><Left>` for python class.

Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

They can be combined just fine, like this for example: <C-M-v> maps CTRL-Alt-v.

Meta (Alt) is M, Shift is S, and CTRL is C.