# Vim multiple meta keys

Tags: ruby, vim, dictionary, meta-key

**Update:** It turns out to be [a bug in MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/detail?id=317) (or perhaps a feature that has yet to be implemented).

---

I am trying Vim, coming from [TextMate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextMate). TextMate has a Ruby plugin where you can type <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, and it will find all the lines in your file that contain "# => ", and it will update them with the inspected result of that line.

I have found the library they use to do this, it's called xmpfilter, and comes with [rcodetools](http://rubygems.org/gems/rcodetools).

So I can get Vim to do the same behaviour by typing "mzggVG:!xmpfilter -a" which will highlight the whole file, go to last line mode, and pass the contents to xmpfilter, and then replace the highlighted contents with the result.

But I want to map it to the same key combination that TextMate uses, so that it has the same interface, because this has become a *huge* piece of my workflow.

Here are a bunch of examples of how I have tried to make this work

```
:nmap <silent> <D-C-E> mzggVG!xmpfilter -a<cr>'z
:nmap <silent> <S-D-C-e> mzggVG!xmpfilter -a<cr>'z
:nmap <silent> <SDC-e> mzggVG!xmpfilter -a<cr>'z
:nmap <silent> <S-<D-<C-e>>> mzggVG!xmpfilter -a<cr>'z
:nmap <silent> <SDC-e> mzggVG!xmpfilter -a<cr>'z
:nmap <silent> <S-><D-><C-e> mzggVG!xmpfilter -a<cr>'z
```

But none of those work correctly. It would seem that **I can't figure out how to specify multiple meta keys**. (As a sanity test, I have verified that `:nmap <silent> <S-e> mzggVG!xmpfilter -a<cr>'z` does work.) Any help would be appreciated.

(Note: I'm using [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) on Snow Leopard)

Comment: I asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456026/can-vim-commands-be-mapped-to-key-combinations-with-1-modifier-e-g-ctrl-alt-v), and the answer I was given worked fine in my case. I was expecting that your first attempt `<D-C-E>` would work, but it doesn't. [The link that GWW provided](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Maping-Ctrl-Shift-s-problems-td1182827.html) seems to confirm that there is no way to create the mapping that you want to, which is a shame!

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken the command key is represented by D not M (M is alt I believe).  I think you'd want to use `<S-D-C-e>`.  ** Note: AS far as I know the command key only works when you are using the GUI.

Comment: Yes, this does seem to be true. I can do, for example, <D-e> to do it. Or, I can do command+shift+e with <D-E>, but can't seem to get the control in there. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Based on this http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Maping-Ctrl-Shift-s-problems-td1182827.html It appears using ctrl is case insensitive.  Perhaps you could use Alt (M) instead of Ctrl (C)?